# OnClickListener not setting up correctly

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make an OnClickListener work with added view(s) and open an Activity but it doesn't seem to work like I made it. It displays an error that says 'cannot resolve constructor ...'. Anyone know how to fix it? Btw I'm pretty new to android development.

EDIT error log:

```
Error:(56, 36) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<teamTasks>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String) is not applicable 
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here's the code, OnClickListener at the very bottom:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class teamCreateScreen extends Activity {

private int counter = 0;
private int lastId = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.team_locate_layout);
}
public void createTeam(View view) {
    final RelativeLayout rlTeam = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlTeam);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setWidth(720);
    tv.setHeight(480);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

        tv.setId(Utils.generateViewId());

    } else {

        tv.setId(View.generateViewId());

    }

    if(lastId == -1) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());
        counter++;
    } else if(counter == 1) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastId);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, lastId);
        counter++;
    } else if(counter == 2) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);
        counter = 1;
    }

    tv.setText("New Team");
    lastId = tv.getId();
    rlTeam.addView(tv, relativeParams);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent showTasks = new Intent(this, teamTasks.class);
            startActivity(showTasks);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please attach error log to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        Intent showTasks = new Intent(this, teamTasks.class);
        startActivity(showTasks);
```

Replace with below lines:

```
        Intent showTasks = new Intent(teamCreateScreen.this, teamTasks.class);
        startActivity(showTasks);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your constructor

```
Intent showTasks = new Intent(this, teamTasks.class);
```

is resolving this to your OnClickListener. You need to change it to reference the outer activity's context, like this:

```
Intent showTasks = new Intent(teamCreateScreen.this, teamTasks.class);
```